# zend-framework output Zend_Db_Table's select() statement generated query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

i want to output the query generated by Zend_Db_Table's select() statement for testing porposes but i dont know how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually really easy. The select object implements a toString method.

```
$select = $table->select()->....
echo $select; //prints SQL
```

Or

```
$sql = $select->__toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

or cast it to string and then use it:

```
(string)$table->select();
```